# Laravel send email: Class 'Swift_Events_CommandEvent' not found

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to send a simple email to the website owner once a user submits the contact form.

However, once the contact form is submitted I get the following error:

exception:

```
"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
```

file: `"/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Events/SimpleEventDispatcher.php"`

line: 61

message: `"Class 'Swift_Events_CommandEvent' not found"`

Comment: try ``composer dumpautoload``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to vendor folder and check if this file `vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Events/CommandEvent.php` exist, else remove vendor folder of swiftmailer and re-install packages.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason the file was blank. Re installed packages and now working.

Answer (score 0):

check your Laravel version. remove the vendor folder.
then,
`composer install`
it will woking